# How to get time and date after certain milliseconds in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, momentjs

**Problem Statement:**
I am trying to get the time and date after certain milliseconds using moment.js
**Example:**

```
const expiresIn = 30000 // milliseconds
const issuedAt = moment().toString();
const expiresAt = // I need to get the time and date after "expiresIn"(milliseconds) so i can set the "expiresAt" as time and date
```

Comment: `moment().add(expiresIn, 'millisecond')`

Answer (score 1):

Do with `setTimeout()`

```js
const expiresIn = 3000 // milliseconds

setTimeout(function(){
 console.log(moment().toString())
},expiresIn)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```